# Installing Atom on D Drive on windows

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to install Atom text editor on Windows. I have a C Drive and a D drive on my windows machine. I have a Windows 7 32 bit machine.

It is by default installing everything on C drive. I would like to install it on D drive. I would also like to install the add on packages for Atom, like project-manager etc. on D drive.

Not able to find an option to do it. Kindly Suggest.

Regards
Bonson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the atom `atom-windows.zip` from the stable release section in https://github.com/atom/atom/releases

Extract it to your `D:\` drive.

And that's mostly it.

You should also probably need to add the `atom` and `apm` commands to your PATH

Comment: I had tried it from the Windows Atom installer.exe which is available on the site. Had installed it after placing it on the D drive. The installer first checks for .NET framework and installs it if it does not exist and then installs atom. All through the process it never asks for a path for installation. It also adds Atom to the Path variable automatically. Will try to do it again from the zip file.

Comment: @Bonson The zip file should be just extract and run. You need to add Atom to the PATH manually, though, but it's not a big deal. Also you will need to install the requirements as .NET framework if Atom says so when trying to run it. I just did it to check if works and I had no problems.

Comment: Can you please explain : How to add atom and npm commands to path??

Comment: @sailens I am using Windows 8

Comment: @Vishal https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9pg2FHeoq8 In this video it is explained how to add a variable to the path